# Shift all zeros to the front or to the back in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Shift all the Zeros to the front or to the back of an array without using data structures or temp array.

```
Original Array
1 9 8 4 0 0 2 7 0 6 0 9 
Array after pushing zeros to the back: 
1 9 8 4 2 7 6 9 0 0 0 0 
Array after pushing zeros to the front: 
0 0 0 0 1 9 8 4 2 7 6 9
```

Comment: is not so clear, can you elaborate and post code example and expected output

Comment: A natural way to "push" all zeros in their place (when talking about an array of numbers) would be **sorting**.

Comment: A common scenario would be to swap a zero element with a non-zero element at the start of the array.

It would be good to show what you have tried to do, expected output and what isn't working

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to:

- maintain an index to the first non-zero item in the array, and
- an index to the item that you are currently scanning.
- Both indexes start at zero.
- If the item that you are currently scanning is not zero, increment
  the scanning index.
- If the item that you are currently scanning is zero, swap it with the
  item at the first non-zero index, and increment both indexes.
- Repeat until the scanning index has reached the end of the array.

Comment: While we are at the commenting-each-other-game: I find your answer could be improved dramatically by adding some vertical spacing (i think the cool people call that "paragraphs"); and maybe a more formal, pseudo code like representation of the algorithm. +1 nonetheless.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking of something like this. Keep index of first and last one. And then keep comparing like that, but is that correct?

Comment: Why dont you give it a try? And hint: if you were "already thinking about that" ... dont come here to ask other people to **teach** you. You learn programming by making your own **experiments**. Just **try** things yourself. That gives a 100 times more "learning effects" than us doing the thinking for you.

Comment: If the intent is to move all zeros to the front, and leave the rest in their original order, sorting is NOT the answer.

Comment: @GhostCat you're a good sport.  ;-)

Comment: @FredK the convention on stackoverflow is to go with the parameters stated in the question, and not invent constraints of our own devise.

Answer (score 1):

The simple, brute force way would be something like reversed insertion sort: you iterate your array, and if you find that

```
a[i] = 0, and a[i-i] != 0 then you swap a[i] and a[i-1]
```

You keep iterating until you can "walk" the whole array without any more swaps.

Comment: This will work, but it is terribly inefficient.  O(N^2).  My solution is O(N).

Comment: I guess me starting my sentence with "simple, brute force" should have warned you. When he is a beginner, it might be helpful to talk about stuff that beginners typically learn first - like "insertion sort". But of course, you are correct.

Comment: Sure.  My comment was not so much to you, (obviously you know,) but to anyone who reads the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that uses java's Arrays.sort method:

```
int[] myArray = new int[10];
// initialize myArray with values...
Arrays.sort(myArray, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        // if o1 is zero, then return a 'less' than value (-1). 
        // otherwise, return an 'equivalent' value (0)
        return o1 == 0 ? -1 : 0;
    }           
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have negative numbers in your array you can just sort it. You can do it in very simple way with using ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
integers.add(5);
integers.add(2);
integers.add(0);
integers.add(44);
integers.add(0);
integers.add(1);
integers.add(555);

integers.forEach(System.out::println);
integers.sort(Integer::compareTo);
System.out.println("Sorted!");
integers.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
5
2
0
44
0
1
555
Sorted!
0
0
1
2
5
44
555
```

However if you do have negative numbers you need to write your own comparator which would look like this:

```
integers.sort((o1, o2) -> o1 == 0 ? -1 : 0);
```

If o1 (one of two numbers) is zero, make it less so it will get lower index.

Note: if you don't want to use ArrayList you can use `Arrays.sort(array, comparator);`